# Creating flamegraphs over specific binary executable

Tags: rust, dtrace, flamegraph

I want to create a `flamegraph` of my Rust executable (which is in `target/release/name-of-binary`). I found the `perf` command to [here](https://gist.github.com/dlaehnemann/df31787c41bd50c0fe223df07cf6eb89)

However, since I'm suing mac os, I don't have `perf` and have to use `dtrace`. Although I figured out how to use `dtrace` for a specific PID, I don't know how to use it for a specific Rust binary. Any help would be appreciated!